# I am unable to accept an invitation to a Trello board - I'm stuck in Trello limbo

Tags: trello

I've been sent an invitation to a Trello board, it's pending and although I've tried to accept it nothing is happening. I then tried to reject it, so that the board owner could resend a new invite... I am also unable to reject it. I have view of the board but cannot be added as a member by the owner because I'm unable to accept the invitation. Has anyone had this problem and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

> **Problems, Bugs, and Crashes**
>
> If you've got a bug to report, please first check the [Trello Development](https://trello.com/board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) board where we maintain a list of known issues and bugs. Bugs have the red label.
>
> If you can't find the bug, are having problems with your account, or are experiencing crashes please email Fog Creek at **support@trello.com**. If you could include the browser, operating system and any errors, it will help us a bunch.

From [Trello help page](https://trello.com/help).