# Unable to accept an add member invitation to Trello

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [I am unable to accept an invitation to a Trello board - I'm stuck in Trello limbo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20329/i-am-unable-to-accept-an-invitation-to-a-trello-board-im-stuck-in-trello-limb)

I tried to add myself to the new board I created in Trello.

What am I doing wrong?

I received an invite with the following information:

> Invitation
>
> XXXX asked you to join the "Operations board"(link) on Trello.
>
> "View Board" (Green Button)
>
> What's Trello?
>
> Use Trello to organize anything, alone or with your co-workers. In one glance, your Trello board tells you what's being worked on, who's doing it, and how close they are to being done.

Comment: That question was closed because bugs should be reported to **support@trello.com**. See the answer to the question you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what your situation is, but it sounds as if you have two trello accounts, and you're trying to get both of them on the same board.

This can be a little bit tricky, because Trello doesn't lock the invitation to the member/email that it was sent to (because the person that is invited may want to accept the invitation with a different account)

Suppose you have two accounts, **Adam** and **Bob**.  You've want to create a board with your **Adam** account, and you want to add your **Bob** account to it as well.

Here is how you would do that:

1. Log in as **Adam**
2. Create the board
3. Invite **Bob**
4. **Log out** of **Adam**'s Trello account, and log into **Bob**'s Trello account (this is important)
5. Check Bob's email
6. Click the **View Board** link
7. Accept the invitation

If you skip step 4, then Trello isn't sure what to do with the invitation, because the currently logged in account is already a member of the board.

**Note:** You could skip step 4 if you logged in as **Bob** in a different browser (or an incognito window), and used that browser to open the link in the invitation email.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, after I click the view board link, where do I accept the invitation? Thanks!

Comment: If you're logged into an account that isn't already a member of the board, and the invitation hasn't already been accepted by another account, there should be a "Accept Invitation" link on the right side, above the list of members.